# How do I add text before the actual list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents

Currently I have:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}

\listoffigures

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    
\newpage
```

And that yields, as expected, the following result:

[image]

How do I move the text before the actual list, but after the title of `\listoffigures`, without it being on it's own page and the list of figures being added to the next page?

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: @campa The report class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\addtocontents`. This also allows to get a more precise placement of the toc entry.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\addtocontents{lof}{%
  \protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}%
  \noindent This is some text I want to have between the
  title and the actual entries\par\bigskip
}

\chapter{Test}

\begin{figure}
\caption{This is for the first entry}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]